# How do I use a variable's value as yaml key in ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Depending on inventory, I'd like to substitute a YAML key with a variable's name in my playbook:

```
config:
  {{ db_name }}:
    other_config
```

At some point later, I use it in template converted it to JSON via `to_nice_json`. However, in the JSON, I see `{{ db_name }}` instead of variable name. Is there any workaround to use the variable value in a key context?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [replace](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/replace_module.html) instead of variable as a key, if you wish to change it in the template.
For example, in the template set a name for a search with regex (CHANGETHISVAR) and use the module:

```
- replace:
    path: /path/to/your/file
    regexp: '(CHANGETHISVAR)'
    replace: 'db_name'
```

Add this routine after running the template task.

Answer (score 0):

> However, in the JSON, I see `{{ db_name }}` instead of a variable name

So you do something wrong "*in the JSON*".

Example:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  vars:
    db_name: DB1
    config: "{'{{ db_name }}':'value'}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: config
```

Result:

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "config": {
        "DB1": "value"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand from the requirement stated here, the following might be a feasible method to generate the dynamic JSON config:

- have the configs in a YAML template file.
- generate YAML config based on hostname etc.
- load variable(s) from the generated YAML file using include_vars and transform it to JSON using to_json filter or similar.